# Service not activated when message in queue after worker process shut down

Tags: wcf, msmq

I have a (dead-letter) queue on my local machine called `logging/logdeadletterservice.svc`.  I have a corresponding service running at `appdev.me.com/logging/logdeadletterservice.svc` to pull the messages from the queue and resubmit them.  This works great so long as the worker process is running.  However, once the worker process is shut down (or if it hasn't come up yet), the service no longer gets messages from the queue unless I browse to the SVC manually.

According to [this post](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/03/17/hosting-a-wcf-service-based-on-msmq-in-iis7/), NETWORK SERVICE needs permissions to peek the queue.  I went ahead and added that permission, but the message was not pulled from the queue.  I tried restarting the Net.Msmq Listener Adapter (which is, indeed, running under Network Service), but still no go.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**:  I've tried [running `sc sidtype netmsmqactivator unrestricted`](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/a1df55c4-e642-442a-9057-f0aec278d10c/) and restarting the service, but no go.  Switched it back to restricted (original) after it didn't resolve the issue.

**EDIT2**:  Also tried running the Net.Msmq Listener Adapter as myself (which is the user under which the service is running), but no go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using [AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx) and running the following commands against appcmd.exe to get the pool to be always available and always warmed up:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set apppool "My Site" /startMode:AlwaysRunning
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set app /app.name:"My Site/My App" /serviceAutoStartEnabled:True /serviceAutoStartMode:All /serviceAutoStartProvider:Service
```